# Получить связанные данные

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть объект, скажем Door. У Door есть параметр Room, значение которому подгружается из базы. Каждая Room относится к своему Building. Т.е., чтобы получить значение Building из Door, нужно примерно следующее: Door.Room.Building. Но он не заполняется автоматически. У Room также есть параметр BuildingReference, через который вероятно и можно получить значение Building. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как это сделать?
Использую edmx.

Решение найдено: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Что-то типа этого:

```
var blogs2 = context.Blogs 
                       .Include("Posts.Comments") 
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: @Bald Не дубликат - там Code First, а тут старый подход.

Comment: @PavelMayorov принципиальные различия будут в организации связей между сущностями, а если навигационные свойства есть то тогда можно воспользоваться той статьей

Comment: @Bald там как минимум для ленивой загрузки не нужен `virtual` (ленивость реализована внутри `EntitySet`). Плюс у явной загрузки другой синтаксис. Применима из того ответа сюда - только жадная загрузка, то есть треть. Слишком мало, чтобы считать дубликатом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov обратите внимание на статью которая помогла в решении вопроса тс. там те же самые подходы, что и в моем вопросе/ответе, если вопрос не будет закрыт как дубликат я ничего против не имею, но и ссылка на него мне кажется уместной. мне больше нравится подход `code first`, может Вы бы расписали про загрузку данных при `model first` подходе, т.е. организация связей и прочие ньюансы, а вновь возникающие вопросы закрывали бы как дубликат

Comment: @Bald ну правильно, он же жадную загрузку и использовал :) Попытался бы что-нибудь другое из той статьи применить - был бы пшик.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение - оформите его в виде ответа, чтобы ваш вопрос не висел в "неотвеченных"

Answer (score 2):

Может так?

```
var Doors = context.Door.Include(x => x.Room.Include(y => y.Building)).toList();
```

При условии что связи в модели правильные.